# detect a change in state of voltage divider without using ADC

Tags: arduino, adc, photoresistor

I am using a photoresistor for a laser trip wire setup to detect motion.
I am a little short of adc channels here so would like to use a simple GPIO to read the state of the photoresistor ckt.
I am looking for something which will give me a HIGH if laser is tripped and LOW if it isn't.
Any ideas ??

Comment: Wouldn't a [Comparator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparator) work when you use the photoresistor in a voltage divider?

Comment: a phototransistor might be a better choice if you want minimal external components

Answer (score 7):

To achieve a logic level input using a photoresistor the following must be known:

- Resistance of the photoresistor in illuminated and non-illuminated state - Use a multimeter to find out.
- GPIO logic level "high" threshold voltage for the microcontroller in question - The datasheet typically provides this.
- Assumption: The GPIO is a high-impedance input - Most modern microcontrollers are.

Once the values above are known, a suitable voltage divider will serve as a level-based trigger for the photoresistor.

To trigger a HIGH if the laser is "tripped", i.e. obscured, this hypothetical photoresistor should be wired on the ground side of the voltage divider, with a fixed resistance on the Vcc side, and the GPIO input pin connected to the junction of these two resistors.

Here are some ***assumed*** values, to illustrate calculations:

- Vcc of circuit: 5 Volts
- Photoresistor values:

  - 1 kOhm when illuminated by the laser
  - 1 MOhm when not illuminated
- IO port thresholds (from ATmega328 datasheet):

  - LOW is  < 0.3 Vcc, i.e. < 1.5 Volts
  - HIGH is > 0.7 Vcc, i.e. > 3.5 Volts
  - Values in between are not defined, so GPIO could read either way.

If we pick 100 kOhm for the fixed resistor, then the voltage at the junction will be...

- When obscured: 4.55 Volts = HIGH
- When illuminated: 0.495 Volts = LOW

Both values leave sufficient margin for reliable triggering of logic level on the GPIO pin, so required solution is achieved.

Answer (score 4):

A cheap technique to measure a variable resistance without an ADC is to see how long it takes to charge a capacitor through it. Connect the capacitor to one of your IO pins. Start a timer then charge the capacitor through your variable resistance. When the state of the IO pin changes, read the timer. That number is proportional to the resistance.

This is how the [game port](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_port) for pre-USB joysticks works.

Comment: This way I get a makeshift ADC channel .
Handy.
Thanks.